# Exclude WP-Filebase files from wordpress search

Tags: wordpress

I use Filebase to manage exclusively private files for a private section of a website. Everything is Ok with custom roles I've created and a private page in which I display the file browser.

However, there is an issue for me because files are accessible via the Wordpress default search tool.

If roles a properly set, these files can be displayed in results with "no access" mention but it would be better to completely exclude them from the search.

Someone knows how can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it uses custom post type (which it probably does), find declaration in the code (you could probably search for `register_post_type` function) and add `'exclude_from_search'=>true` to the array of params

Comment: Thanks. The thing here is that the post type is registered by the plugin and I can't directly modifiy the plugin files. I've tried to find a way to change post type settings after it was registered but I think this specific setting can't be changed :(

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a parameter "Search integration" which seems to do what I need. If unchecked, my problem is solved.

**Search integration:** *Searches in attached files and lists the associated posts and pages when searching the site.*

When I fisrt read this setting, I didn't thought it was refering to the Wordpress search since the plugin has also a search tool.